# JQuery Toggling Dynamically Named Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment I have a tiered list of div boxes each holding a title. At the beginning of each title there is a `-` sign which when clicked hides or displays everything tiered under that div in javascript with a link.

My problem is I'd like to change it over to JQuery but don't really know where to start. I've got jquery running on the page as I've done `$(document).ready(function(){alert("fubar");});` and it alerts correctly, but I don't know where to go from there.

The link on the `-` sign currently has an onclick function of `ShowHideStuff(ChildrenOf[IDValue])` and then the div box it hides/displays is called `ChildrenOf[IDValue]`.

Here is the javascript I'm currently using:

```
function ShowHideStuff(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want do the same using jQuery?

Try this:

```
function ShowHideStuff(id){  
   $('#'+id).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest first having a look at some of the jQuery docs, they're there for a reason.

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

But for your problem, you need a selector for each '-' sign, which could look like this `$('.minus')` . Which selects any element with `class='minus'` (you would have to add the minus class to each '-' element.

The code would then be:

```
$('.minus').click(function(){
  ShowHideStuff(ChildrenOf[IDValue]);
});
```